# can i use gdalinfo to extract specifically just valid time from a grib2 file?

Tags: datetime, epoch, grib

i want to be able to grab valid time from a grib2 file

```
$ gdalinfo this_file_20211018_1300.grib2
```

Output:

```
 ....*a bunch of stuff i dont really need*...
 ....
 .....
 *what i actually need* 
 GRIB_VALID_TIME=  1634590800 sec UTC
```

so it is in UTC seconds.
i want to convert 1634590800 to a date format that looks like this :

```
this_file_20211018_1300.grib2
```

can i use gdalinfo or some other linux utility to extract specifically just valid time from a grib2 file ?

Answer (score 0):

i found a way by just piping grep to the metadata I need :

```
TEMP=`gdalinfo this_pngfile_20211018_1300.grib2 | grep -i GRIB_VALID_TIME -m 1`
IFS=' '
read -a strarr <<< "$TEMP"
EPOCHTIME="${strarr[1]}"
DATEU=`date -d@$EPOCHTIME -u +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
echo "$DATEU.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gdalinfo` with `jq`:

```
gdalinfo -json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f001 | jq -r '.bands | .[0].metadata."".GRIB_VALID_TIME'
1661907600
```